# How do I find the first elelment in my Ruby array matching certain criteria?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to find the first item in my array of objects whose fields match certain criteria.  So I wrote this lengthy loop …

```
    result = nil
    results.each do |r|
      if r.valid?
        result = r 
        break
      end
    end
```

My question is, is there a shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup there is:

```
result = results.find(&:valid?)
```

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find

Thanks to Rashmirathi for the ampersand + colon shortcut!

Comment: I deleted my answer, since we have the same answer essentially.

Comment: Aw okay, sorry :(

I'm not sure who answered first.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do that using Array method select

```
results = [{id: 1, valid: true}, {id: 2, valid: false}, {id:3, valid: true}]
result = results.select { |item|  item[:valid] == true}.first
```

You can find more at array documenation: https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-select